# при повторном ajax запросе ошибка 400

Tags: ajax, yii2, http-status-code-400

Пробую сделать фильтрацию товаров на сайте. Первый запрос проходит успешно, товары фильтруются, но если выбрать какую-либо категорию еще раз, то возвращается код ошибки 400.
Код контроллера

```
 public function actionCatalog(){
        if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
            if($_POST['cat']=='Холодильники'){
                $goods = Good::find()->asArray()->where(['=', 'cat', 'Холодильники'])->all();
                return $this->render('catalog', compact('goods'));
            }elseif ($_POST['cat']=='Телевизоры'){
                $goods = Good::find()->asArray()->where(['=', 'cat', 'Телевизоры'])->all();
                return $this->render('catalog', compact('goods'));
            }

        }else {
            $goods = Good::find()->asArray()->where(['!=', 'img', ''])->all();
            return $this->render('catalog', compact('goods'));
        }
    }
```

Вот ajax

```
$('#icebox').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url : '',
        data: {cat: 'Холодильники'},
        type: 'POST',

        success: function (res) {
            document.write(res);
            $('#icebox').empty();

        },
        error: function () {
            alert('mistake');
        }

    });
});
$('#tv').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url : '',
        data: {cat: 'Телевизоры'},
        type: 'POST',

        success: function (res) {
            document.write(res);
            $('#tv').empty();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('mistake');
        }

    });
});
```

Yii дебаг панель

```
yii\web\BadRequestHttpException: Не удалось проверить переданные
данные. in
C:\OpenServer\domains\net-shop\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Controller.php:166
Stack trace:
#0 C:\OpenServer\domains\net-shop\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(154):
yii\web\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#1 C:\OpenServer\domains\net-shop\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(523):
yii\base\Controller->runAction('catalog', Array)
#2 C:\OpenServer\domains\net-shop\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(102):
yii\base\Module->runAction('post/catalog', Array)
#3 C:\OpenServer\domains\net-shop\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(380):
yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#4 C:\OpenServer\domains\net-shop\web\index.php(13): yii\base\Application->run()
#5 {main}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А вы уверены, что `$_POST['cat']` существует и имеет значение `Холодильники` или `Телевизоры`? А то может ни одно условие не выполняется :Р

Comment: @Visman, так при первом же запросе все фильтруется, то есть  `$_POST['cat']` существует и даже имеет нужные значения, но вот при последующих запросах почему-то возвращается ошибка

Comment: А в дебаг-панели смотрели что за ошибка?

Comment: @Pa3Py6aka, строка ошибки `xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );` >Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: @Kreol, это ошибка в консоли браузера как я понимаю? А дебаг самого yii2 подключен?

Comment: @Pa3Py6aka, дополнил проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При отправке ajax-запросов в `data` добавь csrf-токен:

```
data: {cat: 'Холодильники', _csrf: yii.getCsrfToken()},
```

Comment: это помогло, спасибо, но почему при первом запросе все было успешно?

Comment: первый запрос через ajax или первый запрос это запрос при загрузки страницы?